# How to prove this series converges ?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have this series

$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\left(\sqrt[n]{n}-1\right)^n$
Im having truoble to prove that this converges, 
I've tryind to use the ratio test but it didnt seem to get me to something that will be easy enough to calculate the limit.

any advices ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Root Test! We have 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}((\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^n)^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)=0.$$

*Another way:* After a while, $0\lt \sqrt[n]{n}-1\le \frac{1}{2}$. Now do a comparison with the convergent geometric series $\sum \frac{1}{2^n}$.

Comment: Just to understande this series, because i've look at the graph of the ${a_n}$ compare to the same series but insteat of power  by n, let say it was power by 3 $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\left(\sqrt[n]{n}-1\right)^3$. they kinda have the same speed (?) to zero, it this also converges ?

Comment: @limitless That series converges too, but the terms go to $0$ much more slowly than the terms of the original series.

Comment: The speed of convergence to $0$ of the cube is far far slower than the speed of convergence of the $n$-th power. We need some information about the speed of convergence of $\sqrt[n]{n}-1$. For your question about cubes, Jack D'Aurizio's bound gives good enough information, the sum of the cubes converges faster than $\sum \frac{\ln^3 n}{n^3}$, which converges.

Answer (score 2):

Write $n$ as:
$$ n=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{k+1}{k}=1\cdot\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right) $$
and apply the AM-GM inequality:
$$ \sqrt[n]{n} \leq 1+\frac{H_{n-1}}{n}. $$
The last inequality trivially implies that your series is convergent.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the $\;n\,-$ th root test directly (you can as your series is non-negative):

$$\sqrt[n]{\left(\sqrt[n]n-1\right)^n}=\sqrt[n]n-1\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0<1$$

so your series converges

Answer (score 1):

Let $q \in (0,1)$. Since
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n} = 1$$
It follows that there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N$ we have
$$|\sqrt[n]{n} - 1| \leq q$$
Hence
$$\sum_{n=N}^\infty (\sqrt[n]{n} - 1)^n \leq \sum_{n=N}^\infty q^n < \infty$$
Convergence follows since the whole sum can now be evaluated to be smaller than some finite terms plus a  convergent sum.